# Describing curve $C: f(x,y)=0$ as graph of a function $x=g(y)$ near $(1,1)$ with $f(x,y)=x^3+x^2 \ln(y)-y$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

$f(x,y)=x^3+x^2 \ln(y)-y$.

How can I show that in a neighborhood of $x_0=(1,1)$ the curve $C:f(x,y)=0$ can be locally described as graph of a function $x=g(y)$? I also need to determine $g'(1)$ but this should be doable once I know what $g(y)$ is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the Implicit Function Theorem?

Answer (score 0):

We have $f(x_0)=0$ and $f_x(x_0) \ne 0$. Hence the existence of a function $x=g(y)$ is garanteed by the Implicit Function Theorem.

Furthermore we have

$0=f(g(y),y)$ in a neiborhood $U$ of $1$. Thus, by the chain rule:

$(*) \quad 0=f_x(g(y),y)g'(y)+f_y(g(y),y)$ for all $y \in U$.

Since $g(1)=1$ you can compute $g'(1)$ with $(*)$.